# iPhone - Online Multiplayer game tutorial using game center

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to implement game center to do an online multiplayer in my app, but reading Apple docs is like trying to decipher an alien inscription found on a monolith in mars, blindfolded. I have tried these tutorials by Ray Wenderlichs [Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12) and [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22), but they are not working (match never starts because inviting device never receives the match acceptance).

Is there any tutorial created to teach this as we would do to teach a 5 y.o. children? Do this, then do this, then do this and not require exoteric powers to understand?

Please don't mention any tutorial, sample or doc from Apple (or I will snap). Apple is great for creating amazing devices, but all their docs stink infinity squared. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think Apple's docs are quite wonderful. Please don't snap. :)

But they won't give you detailed, step-by-step, handholding advice for a reason: this level of detail is prone to frequent changes, and depends on a number of factors (ie device, OS version, SDK version, bluetooth, Wifi, 3G, etc.) that it is almost guaranteed that your experience will vary. The same problem of course arises when a helpful developer writes a tutorial. Meaning: the more detailed the description the more likely it'll fail for a greater number of people, more so the older the article is.

Anyhow, usually if the other device doesn't respond there are often simple reasons that aren't directly related to the code. From the top of my head these are all issues I've ran into before:

- use a unique Game Center account for every device
- make sure your Game Center accounts are in sandbox mode
- make sure your app identifier is registered in Game Center
- make sure you run the same code on both devices (ie not two different projects, possibly using different code)
- make sure both devices can connect to the Internet (not just to your local Wifi network)
- make sure the local player is authenticated before proceeding (log this)

There's probably a dozen or more of these kinds of issues. I'm pretty sure Ray's tutorial works in general. And you'll hardly find any other tutorials more descriptive than his.

Comment: Sorry, but I still think Apple docs stink. Just compare a book by any good author, your books for example, with their docs. It is like comparing shakespeare with the yellow pages. Their docs are written by people that don't have didactics. I also write books in my natural language, so I know what I am talking about. They write like telegrams. Short vague descriptions that say nothing to anyone, except for half a dozen people.

Comment: I know now, why there's so few games with game center on the store (I mean turn based or real multiplayer games), compared to the total number of games. I was able to identify no more than 100 games... in 500 K games total is pretty low. The reason is that their docs stinks. Regarding to Ray's tutorial.... just download their final project and try to run and you will see that the project is not working. Something is wrong and the app is not receiving and processing the invitation acceptance. So, the tutorial is useless as it is.

Comment: As I am trying to understand game center, I don't know what is wrong with Ray's project. If you can check that out and see what's going on, I appreciate. Thanks. The project is at the end of the second part.